# How can I add two values in an array that belong to the same user?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to display a total score. I am getting the individual scores below. Each user has two "sets" in which they have a score.

```
foreach ($user['results'] as $result) {   
    error_log($result['user_id']);
    error_log($result['score']);
}
```

The above returns this in the logs:

```
10938  // user_id
16.00  // score
10938  // user_id
12.00  // score
...
```

What I am trying to do is add `16.00` + `12.00` to get a total score of `28`. Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use array_sum and array_chunk

```
$arr = array_chunk($user['results'], 2);
$sums = array_map(function($v){return array_sum(array_column($v, 'score'));}, $arr);
```

Comment: There are few ones, For getting the badges they keep on downvoting and upvoting randomly. Without seeing whether it is right or wrong.

Comment: Thank you! For anyone else, here is how I output the result to my table:
`$markup .= '<td class="text-center">' . $sums[0] . '</td>';`

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple one.. Here we are `adding all scores` according to `user_id` first and then we are writing to logs.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/790890)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//-----------------------------sample array
$user['results']=array(
    array("user_id"=>"10938","score"=>"16.00"),
    array("user_id"=>"10931","score"=>"13.00"),
    array("user_id"=>"10938","score"=>"12.00"),
    array("user_id"=>"10931","score"=>"12.00"),
    array("user_id"=>"10935","score"=>"13.00"),
);

//-------------------gathering logs data.
$logsArray=array();
foreach($user['results'] as $result)
{
    if(!isset($logsArray[$result["user_id"]]))
    {
        $logsArray[$result["user_id"]]=$result;
    }
    else
    {
        $logsArray[$result["user_id"]]["score"]+=$result["score"];
    }
}
print_r($logsArray);
//--------------------- writing to logs
foreach($logsArray as $result)
{
    error_log($result['user_id']);
    error_log($result['score']);
}
```